# How to ask for entities having more than 1 nested entity using the generated C# OData client code?

Tags: c#, odata

I am playing with the TripPin OData demo from https://github.com/OData/ODataSamples/tree/master/Scenarios/TripPin/src/webapi using the OData C# client code generated by the OData template introduced by the following VS extension: [image]

The C# code is simple:

```
var dc = new DefaultContainer(new Uri("http://canws212:23890/"));
dc.People.AddQueryOption("$expand", "Trips").Where(p => p.Trips.Any()).First();
```

This returns the first `Person` entity having any `Trip` child entities in the `Trips` property.

But now I wish to get the first `Person` entity having more than one `Trip` child:

```
dc.People.AddQueryOption("$expand", "Trips").Where(p => p.Trips.Count() > 1).First();
```

This does not work. The request/response as captured by fiddler are:

**Request**

```
GET http://canws212:23890/People?$filter=Trips/$count%20gt%201&$top=1&$expand=Trips HTTP/1.1
OData-Version: 4.0
OData-MaxVersion: 4.0
Accept: application/json;odata.metadata=minimal
Accept-Charset: UTF-8
User-Agent: Microsoft ADO.NET Data Services
Host: canws212:23890
Connection: Keep-Alive
```

**Response**

```
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Type: application/json; odata.metadata=minimal; charset=utf-8
Expires: -1
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.0
OData-Version: 4.0
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-SourceFiles: =?UTF-8?B?RDpcRGF5Zm9yY2VcU291cmNlXFJlcG9zXE9EYXRhU2FtcGxlc1xTY2VuYXJpb3NcVHJpcFBpblxzcmNcd2ViYXBpXE9EYXRhU2FtcGxlcy5XZWJBcGlTZXJ2aWNlXFBlb3BsZQ==?=
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Sat, 23 Jul 2016 01:23:41 GMT
Content-Length: 1604

{
  "error":{
    "code":"","message":"The query specified in the URI is not valid. The method or operation is not implemented.","innererror":{
      "message":"The method or operation is not implemented.","type":"System.NotImplementedException","stacktrace":"   at Microsoft.OData.Core.UriParser.Visitors.QueryNodeVisitor`1.Visit(CountNode nodeIn)\r\n   at Microsoft.OData.Core.UriParser.Semantic.CountNode.Accept[T](QueryNodeVisitor`1 visitor)\r\n   at System.Web.OData.Query.ParameterAliasNodeTranslator.Visit(BinaryOperatorNode nodeIn)\r\n   at Microsoft.OData.Core.UriParser.Semantic.BinaryOperatorNode.Accept[T](QueryNodeVisitor`1 visitor)\r\n   at System.Web.OData.Query.FilterQueryOption.get_FilterClause()\r\n   at System.Web.OData.Query.Validators.FilterQueryValidator.Validate(FilterQueryOption filterQueryOption, ODataValidationSettings settings)\r\n   at System.Web.OData.Query.FilterQueryOption.Validate(ODataValidationSettings validationSettings)\r\n   at System.Web.OData.Query.Validators.ODataQueryValidator.Validate(ODataQueryOptions options, ODataValidationSettings validationSettings)\r\n   at System.Web.OData.Query.ODataQueryOptions.Validate(ODataValidationSettings validationSettings)\r\n   at System.Web.OData.EnableQueryAttribute.ValidateQuery(HttpRequestMessage request, ODataQueryOptions queryOptions)\r\n   at System.Web.OData.EnableQueryAttribute.ExecuteQuery(Object response, HttpRequestMessage request, HttpActionDescriptor actionDescriptor)\r\n   at System.Web.OData.EnableQueryAttribute.OnActionExecuted(HttpActionExecutedContext actionExecutedContext)"
    }
  }
}
```

What is wrong? Is it a defect of the sample TripPin application or am I doing something wrong? How do I fix it?

**EDIT**

I would like the filtration to occur on the database itself. I.e. situation where first all the Person entities are fetched and then filtered out is far from ideal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you run the c# code

```
dc.People.AddQueryOption("$expand", "Trips").Where(p => p.Trips.Count() > 1).First();
```

Odata.Client API convert the query to URL.

The generated url in your case is:

```
http://canws212:23890/People?$filter=Trips/$count gt 1&$top=1&$expand=Trips
```

which doesn't match the URL Convention of OData V4

$filter is applied only on the properties of class (People) , and the class People  can't navigate to the class Trip using  the $filter keyword and there is no property count.

You expand Trips by the keyword Expand

to read more about OData Version 4.0. URL Conventions :

http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata/v4.0/odata-v4.0-part2-url-conventions.html

so, you get the error message

**Edit2:**

To get the first Person entity having more than one Trip

(I test it with url:  http://services.odata.org/V4/TripPinServiceRW )

```
 var dc = new DefaultContainer(new Uri("http://canws212:23890"));
 var firstPerson = dc.People.AddQueryOption("$expand", "Trips")
                            .ToList()
                            .FirstOrDefault(p => p.Trips.Count > 1);
 Console.WriteLine("{0} have: {1} trip", firstPerson.FirstName, firstPerson.Trips.Count);
//The result: Russell have: 3 trip
```

**Edit: 3**
if you review example 28, in the url:

http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata/v4.0/odata-v4.0-part2-url-conventions.html

```
Example 28: entity count in a $filter expression.  
http://host/service/Categories?$filter=Products/$count gt 0
```

you find that V4 support count property
so ,**MY Conclusion**

**TripPin Demo site doesn't comply with URL Convention V4**

and your query is valid , but can't be executed(for no count support)

```
  http://canws212:23890/People?$filter=Trips/$count gt 1&$top=1&$expand=Trips
```

Comment: The solution you are proposing does not work. Have you tested it?

Comment: I modified the code , it is working, can you review :)

Comment: Well, you fetch **ALL** the people and then do filtering in memory on the client side. While technically you did it, but this is hardly what you want to do if you have 10,000 people without any or just one trip and one that matches your criteria. The idea of LINQ to Sql is to avoid this kind of situation and this is what I expect from the OData C# client code.

Comment: OData  don't return this big size of data at all(there is max limit result by server ), and you have to use $top,$skip to paginate data. OData is controlled by its URL standard convention limitation, and can't be compared with Linq to Sql for IQuerable objects. e.g , Trip is a navigation property for people , so you can dc.People , but you can't dc.Trip. Shortly we are controlled by OData Url Limitation.

Comment: Your sample sends a request for all the Persons. The OData controller does not contain explicit code to limit the returned payload - this seems to be the case in the TripPin application, unless I am missing something behind the scenes. So, are you implying there is still a mechanism to limit the amount of the returned entities without the code doing anything?  I need to check it. The point is still that your code filters the persons on the client side instead of specifying a filter to be run in the database. You are saying it is not possible. I am not convinced.

Comment: It could be that TripPin is missing a controller action, which could be added. That is fine, I can add it.